# How to correctly display a gridview into a fragment

Tags: android, gridview, android-fragments

this is my first post on stackoverflow, so please excuse any shortcomings I might be having with norms. 
I'm trying to have a tabbed view on an application, and have each tabbed view (just a normal fragment)  be a gridview. I thought I could just put the initialization code for the gridview in the onCreateView, but ive been at this problem for a couple hours now, and the gridview is returning null in the findviewbyid call. Here's the relevant code (I'm trying not make this question overwhelming , so I won't post all the code

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //            View rootView = inflater.inflate(
    //                    R.layout.fragment_main_ingredient_dummy, container, false);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) inflater.inflate(R.id.gridview, container);
    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity()));  

    return gridview; 
}
```

As I said. the fragment is an ordinary fragment, and its being "managed" by a FragmentPagerAdapter. However, I also have an extension of a BaseAdapter, for teh content inside the actual tab.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can't inflate a view like that.  The inflate call needs an R.layout. reference, not an R.id. reference.

You should only create the view in onCreateView.  Then do the other work in onViewCreated.

```
private GridView mGridView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {;

mGridView = (GridView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_grid, container);


return mGridView; 
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(){
 mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});

mGridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity()));  
}
```